# OSX - Android Emulator closed because of an internal error

Tags: mojave, gpu, android

Trying to run an emulator via a fresh install of Android Studio (3.5) on a new MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019) and the emulator fails to start with the error message below.

I have attempted re-installing HAXM, re-installing Android Studio, creating a new AVD - all with no luck.

About This Mac shows: Display = Radeon Pro 555X 4 GB Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB. The current drivers installed are only those that came pre-installed with the machine

Has anyone experienced this issue and found a fix?

[image]